# How to display a property of an object in select list in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am binding state object from states list but I want to initialize that field with object.name, how can I do it in angular js

Comment: Add more details. And your code so far. Read [mcve].

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

Add more details to get the correct answer...although heres some info which you might be looking

--> you can initialise any model with ng-init directive eg. ng-init="object.namekey"

--> for drop down list

```
    <select ng-model="statesObject" ng-options="y.name for (x, y) in states">
</select>
```

--> and by the way you can get any object's name in javascript with **myObj.constructor.name**

---

Updated answer according to your comment

```
<select ng-model="States[0]" ng-options="state as state.stateName for state in States" name="State" required>
<option value="">Select State</option> </select>

$scope.States = [{stateName:'State1'},{stateName:'State1'},{stateName:'State3'},{stateName:'State4'}];
```

ng-model will do the trick....you just have to give the reference of the object from States array which you are using in ng-select

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/rlArYYM8ygDB2IM8kG6M?p=preview

Comment: //selecting state
<select  ng-model="State" ng-options="state as  state.stateName for state in States"  name="State"  required>
         <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>

//while editing i want to display the selected state as default in drop down but this is not working
<select  ng-model="State" ng-init="State.stateName" ng-options="state as  state.stateName for state in States"  name="State"  required>
        <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>